# Bootstrap panel footer and body overlap when scroll

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` panel inside a section and the `overflow-y` of panel body is `scrollable`.
So when I am scrolling, the footer and body content seems to be overlapped.

```
    <section class="panel panel-featured">
      <header class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-actions"><a href="#" class="fa fa-caret-down"></a></div>
        <h2 class="panel-title">Test Data</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="panel-body custom-scroll" style="max-height: 332px;">

        <div class="col-md-12"> Testing div</div><div class="col-md-12"> Testing div</div>

        <div class="col-md-12"> Testing div</div><div class="col-md-12"> Testing div</div>
      </div>


      <footer class="panel-footer text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Hit Me
        </button>
      </footer>
    </section>
```

[image]

I tried using `Z-index` to resolved this. Is there any way to remove this overlap when scrolling the panel body ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that an additional class was being applied to modal footer from some custom file i.e.,

```
.modal-footer {
   margin-top: -5px;
}
```

That is why there was a overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `overflow-y:scroll` it seems to work fine..

http://codeply.com/go/np6EMwca4p

Comment: it is working fine in codeply link you gave but I am still figuring out why it is not working in my local.

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow:scroll` on `.panel-body custom-scroll` class not `body`.
There is [jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/piguqomote/1/edit?html,css,output)